# Windows Bash file to prioritize execution of redundant .exe files

Tags: windows, security, powershell, file-shortcut

I use a password manager for all of my passwords. The preferred .exe is run from an encrypted USB-Drive. I have a backup on my laptop inside a VeraCrypt container, and another hosted on a server.

I prefer to only use my portable version unless I happened to lose it or don't have access to it. Instead of manually opening the directory and running the .exe file I want to use, I'd like to automate the process as:

```java
File pManager = PasswordManager.exe
File U = USB.pManager
File L = Laptop.pManager
File S = Server.pManager

if (USB.isConnected && U.isPresent): Run --> U
if (!USB.isConnected && L.isPresent): Run => L
else (Server.Connect)
  if (S.isPresent): Run=> S
    else:
     Message("Find your USB Key!")
```

I have tried executing the logic line-by-line in bash/cmd/PowerShell - this works but is more work than simply opening the directories. I then began writing a shell script to automate the process, but quickly realized that I would have to store some of my credentials in plaintext, which I would like to avoid. I don't need help with writing the code; after searching I cannot find the best procedure to automate this process.

What type of execution method (shell script, C/Java program) would be the most streamlined way to automate this process without exposing credentials to someone who may gain access to the file?

Comment: It is not possible with Shell Links aka. Desktop Shortcuts .lnk file. But a script can be create to do it e.g. vbscript, powershell, batch script or a simple C program.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill I certainly don't expect anyone to write the code for me. I did some searching for where to start tackling this (perhaps I'm not using the correct vocabulary) but couldn't come up with anything. I'm simply trying to figure out the starting point for this.

Comment: As for this [I would have to store some of my credentials in plaintext], no you do not. You have several methods of storing and using credentials as safe a possible with PowerShell. There are many articles all over the web regarding securing credentials in Powershell scripts. There are even modules in the MS powershelgallery.com for this use case, say using the Windows Credential Manager (storage/retrieval). Yet this effort requires thought and planning, especially if you are not doing this only on your own host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch file solved my problems, does not leave any CMD windows hanging afterwards, and checks to ensure that the process it not running and that the drive is mounted already.

The same logic can be used for any file that exists in multiple locations. The only time a CMD window stays open is if the process is already running.

If you don't care to be notified of an already running process remove the `:ProcessFound` section and direct the conditional statement to `goto END`:

```sh
:: Batch file to open Password Manager. Prefer .exe located on USB drive
:: If USB not mounted, open local (D:) version.

@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

set EXE=PWManager.exe
set USB="F:\Password\PWManager.exe"
set HDD="D:\Software\Password\PWManager.exe"

FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto ProcessFound

goto ProcessNotFound

:ProcessFound
echo %EXE% is already running. Ensure it is running from the correct location...
pause
goto END

:ProcessNotFound
if exist f:\ (
    goto USBMounted
    
)
goto USBNotMounted

:USBMounted
start "" %USB%
goto END

:USBNotMounted
start "" %HDD%
goto END

:END
exit
```